# neo4j - how to run queries with 1000 objects via rest api

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm need run queries with 1000 objects. Using `/batch` endpoint I can get this to work but is too slow (30 seconds with 300 items).

So I'm trying the same approach as said in this docs page: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.1/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-create-mutiple-nodes-with-properties

POST this JSON to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`

```
{
    "params": {
        "props": [
            {
                "_user_id": "177032492760",
                "_user_name": "John"
            },
            {
                "_user_id": "177032492760",
                "_user_name": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "_user_id": "100007496328",
                "_user_name": "Wilber"
            }
        ]
    },
    "query": "MERGE (user:People {id:{_user_id}}) SET user.id = {_user_id}, user.name = {_user_name} "
}
```

The problem is I'm getting this error:

```
{ message: 'Expected a parameter named _user_id',
  exception: 'ParameterNotFoundException',
  fullname: 'org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException',
  stacktrace:
  ...
```

Maybe this works only with CREATE queries, as showing in the docs page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use FOREACH and MERGE with ON CREATE SET:

```
 FOREACH (p in {props} | 
    MERGE (user:People {id:{p._user_id}}) 
      ON CREATE  user.name = {p._user_name})
```

POST this JSON to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher`

```
{
    "params": {
        "props": [
            {
                "_user_id": "177032492760",
                "_user_name": "John"
            },
            {
                "_user_id": "177032492760",
                "_user_name": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "_user_id": "100007496328",
                "_user_name": "Wilber"
            }
        ]
    },
    "query": "FOREACH (p in {props} | MERGE (user:People {id:{p._user_id}}) ON CREATE  user.name = {p._user_name}) "
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the equivalent to the example in the doc would be:

```
{
    "params": {
        "props": [
            {
                "id": "177032492760",
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "id": "177032492760",
                "name": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "id": "100007496328",
                "name": "Wilber"
            }
        ]
    },
    "query": "CREATE (user:People {props})"
}
```

It might be legal to replace CREATE to MERGE, but the query may not do what you expect.

For example, if a node with the id "177032492760" already exists, but it does not have the name "John", then the MERGE will create a new node; and you'd end up with 2 nodes with the same id (but different names).

Comment: I really need unique id nodes with incremental data because properties can be differents each request. I ll try this. thanks!

Comment: just for know: using this CREATE query only, it is extremely fast. 1000 objects in 2 seconds without changes in CPU/RAM usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `CREATE` statement can take an array of maps and implicitly convert it to several statements with one map each, but you can't use arrays of maps that way outside of simple create statements. In fact you can't use literal maps the same way either when you use `MERGE` and `MATCH`. You can `CREATE ({map})` but you have to `MATCH/MERGE ({prop:{map}.val}` i.e.

```
// {props:{name:Fred, age:2}}
MERGE (a {name:{props}.name}) 
    ON CREATE SET a = {props}
```

For your purposes either send individual parameter maps with a query like above or for an array of maps iterate through it with `FOREACH`

```
FOREACH (p IN props |
    MERGE (user:People {id:p._user_id}) 
        ON CREATE SET user = p)
```