# Neo4j MERGE using REST API

Tags: rest, neo4j

I am attempting to execute a MERGE function using Neo4j's REST API, and I am having a difficult time getting it to work.  I have been leaning on the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799123/neo4j-how-to-run-queries-with-1000-objects-via-rest-api/24111308), however even when I copy the REST content of that answer directly, I still get a `(400) Bad Request` error.

I am using a URL of `http://<username>:<password>@<server IP>:7474/db/data/cypher`.  Other REST calls are working just find; I just can't get this one to go.

Here is the content of my REST request

```
{
  "params": {
    "props": [
      {
        "SerialNo": "AA",
        "Model": "2",
        "ProcessStatus": "-8",
        "FinalStepReached": "False"
      },
      {
        "SerialNo": "AB",
        "Model": "2",
        "ProcessStatus": "-8",
        "FinalStepReached": "False"
      },
      {
        "SerialNo": "AB",
        "Model": "3",
        "ProcessStatus": "-9",
        "FinalStepReached": "False"
      }
    ]
  },
  "query": "FOREACH (p in {props} | MERGE (n:Part {SerialNo:{p.SerialNo}}) ON CREATE  n.Model = {p.Model}) "
}
```

I am running Neo4j server v2.1.0-M01.

Any assistance you could offer would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the curly braces around `p.SerialNo` and `p.Model` in your query.

Also, it seems you forgot the `SET` keyword after `ON CREATE`.

Doesn't the 400 response contain any details regarding the actual error? Check the content.

Comment: +1, once they're in the query with {props} they don't need the brackets anymore.

Comment: I tried this, and I still get a `400 Bad Request` error.  I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: Ah HA!!!  That was it!!  It was the combination of both the items that you indicated: The extra curly braces and the missing "SET" command.